# iOS 12 notifications appearing twice or not at all

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

Hi everyone I have 2 problems with my iPhone 6s since upgrading to iOS 12 (not sure if this has anything to do with it).

1. For the past week I’ve been getting Messenger and text message notification banners show up twice. So for example, the banner will pop up on screen whilst unlocked, then later the notification will pop up again on my lock screen. Or the same banner will show up twice within a few minutes whilst unlocked.
2. Sometimes my messenger and text message notifications don’t show up at all, either when unlocked or on the lock screen. This is annoying because then I’ll go for a long time waiting for a reply when in fact I received it a while back and didn’t know.

Does anyone know what might be up?

Thanks!

Comment: Messages specifically will resend notifications 2 minutes later by default. If you go into the settings for Messages Notifications, is it set to do this?

Comment: Thanks I just checked (didn’t know about that) and repeat alerts was set to “never.” Also there seems to be no such function for Messenger that I can see??

Comment: Yeah, that would only apply for Messages, it's not a regular option.

Comment: It’s appearing twice even for Snapchat as well :/

Answer (score 2):

just thought I would add this started happening a few weeks ago and that my boyfriend (who I suspect is slightly psychopathic) has access to my passcode and often says stuff about me he shouldn’t really know. Yesterday I googled phone hacking and cyberstalking and mysteriously the double notifications seem to have disappeared... please help!